# Google VR + Unity + iOS

Tags: ios, google-vr-sdk

I'm new to AR, Unity and 360° (Google VR). I wish to implement the Google VR view but without the cardboard view. I've imported the Google VR sdk for Unity and have been able to implement the cardboard-like view so far.Is there a way to change the VR view to a single screen in Unity? or would I have to edit the project in Xcode?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's very easy to remove the "vr view". Exactly how depends on which version of the SDK you have.

If you are using the latest version of the GVR plugin, I believe it assumes you have Unity version 5.6 or later, which actually does the vr stuff (mostly) for it. The code to turn it off looks like this: `VRSettings.enabled = false;`

In older versions of the google cardboard API, (before 0.7 or so), you would use `Cardboard.SDK.VRModeEnabled = false;`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible.
Primarily, the Google VR SDK supports VR experiences that are either immersive(using a VR headset) or non-immersive(using just the phone's screen, but still a stereoscopic view). To achieve a single-screen view, you might need to adjust the settings within Unity or modify the camera configuration to render a monoscopic view instead of the default stereoscopic view.